# How to count Transfer-Encoding: chunked chunk size

Tags: html, transfer-encoding

I'm not getting that in Transfer-Encoding: chunked, how the size is counted. can anyone explain this chunk size please? thank you.

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: your-lab-id.web-security-academy.net
Content-length: 4
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

87
GET /admin/delete?username=carlos HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 15

x=1
0
```

Comment: Your question and example content don't add up. There's no mention of `Transfer-encoding: chunked` there, not 15 bytes of data... What's that `87` at the start..?

Comment: Sorry, I just wanted the chunk size to understand, But I edited the post and it has the full request.

Comment: It still doesn't make sense. You're claiming you're sending 4 bytes of content in your `Content-length` header, then your chunk header says "here's 87 bytes in this chunk".

Comment: Have you read the Wikipedia article? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding#Format

Answer (score 1):

When studying about http request smuggling, I struggle too in working out how the chunk size is counted. I've found the example from wikipedia to be very helpful ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding#Example).

So let me try to help you out here, as this is actually a good exercise for me too.

```
87
GET /admin/delete?username=carlos HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 15

x=1
0
```

87 there is in hex form. In decimal form, its 135. Thus the chunks size is 135 bytes.

Then, for every line below 87 we count every characters (assuming 1 character equals 1 byte) and then add 2 bytes for CRLF (`\r\n`), except for the last line above `0` which we don't need to count the trailing CRLF.

Thus it goes something like this:

```
GET /admin/delete?username=carlos HTTP/1.1 -> 42 + 2 bytes for \r\n = 44 bytes
Host: localhost -> 15 + 2 = 17 bytes
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded -> 47 + 2 = 49 bytes
Content-Length: 15 -> 18 + 2 -> 20 bytes
 -> 0 + 2 = 2 bytes
x=1 -> 3 bytes
```

Thus in total there are 135 bytes of chunked data.

Hope this could help.